# Map points from one 2D plane to another

Tags: mapping, points, nonlinear-functions

Given a point on a plane A, I want to be able to map to its corresponding point on plane B. I have a set of N corresponding pairs of reference points between the two planes, however, the overall mapping is not a simple affine transform (no homographies for me).

Things I have tried:

- For a given point, find the three closest reference points in plane A, compute barrycentric coordinates of that triangle, and then apply that transform to the corresponding reference points in plane B. How it failed: sometimes the three closest points were nearly collinear, so errors were huge. Also, there was no consistency in the mapping when crossing borders. It was very "jittery."
- Compute all possible triangles given the N reference points (N^3). Order them by size. For the given point, find the smallest triangle that it's in. This fixes the linearly of the
  points problem, but was still extremely jittery and slow.
- Start with a triangulated plane A. Iterate through the reference points, adding each one to the reference plane. Every time you add a point it exists in at least one triangle. Break that triangle into three triangles using the new reference point as a vertex. You end up with plane A triangulated so you can map from plane A to plane B with ease. Issues: You can prove that every triangle will have a point that is on the edge of the planes. This results in huge errors if your reference points are far from the edge of the planes.

I feel like this should be a fairly standard problem. Are there standard algorithms/libraries for this?

Answer (score 0):

There you go my friend.. I have used it myslef and can only recommend you give it a try.

> #### Kahn Academy - Matrix transformations
>
> Understanding how we can map one set of vectors to another set. Matrices used to define linear transformations
>
> https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/matrix_transformations

Comment: Matrix transformations only work for affine transforms, which locally (between any three points) these are, but global, these are not. Finding barrycentric coordinates and calculating the corresponding plane B location is the same thing as doing a matrix transformation, which is also called finding a homography. I am looking to map a set of points in a non-linear/non-affine fashion.